# Implementing a class with a dynamic datatype attribute C#

Tags: c#, json, class, variables, types

i want to implement a class that one of the attribute is dynamic but i can't seem to figure out how to do that...

```
public class myClass
{
    public datetime timeStamp { get; set;  }
    public object variable { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

I need to read a archive that has the type of the "variable" inside as a integer, for example

This is just an exaple of a json or something that i will use, the "variable" attribute of the clas (in this example) will be a string, but there are sometimes that this attribute should be a integer(example2)

Ex1:

```
{"name" : "Variable1" , "variable" : "string" : "myString" , "timeStamp" : "852852852" }
```

Ex2:

```
{"name" : "Variable2" , "variable" : "int32" : "125125" , "timeStamp" : "852852852" }
```

Comment: How does the sample string relate to your `OPC_UA` class?  It is hard to understand what you are asking...

Comment: The "object" value is the dynamic attribute that i need to change on each instance of a class, on that json example i would instantiate one opc_ua object with name = "Variable1" and variable being of datatype string

Comment: So the name has to change, _and_ the type?  It would really help if you posted JSON samples, because its still not clear what you are asking

Comment: I just eddited the question to be more clear, i'm not using json yet, this is just a prototype... i need to know some way that i can make the "variable" datatype to be dinamic, i'll read some value and if in the file i'll read it's written "int", it should be an integer

Comment: Just use `dynamic` as the `variable` type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make OPC_UA a generic class:

```
class OPC_UA<T>
{
    public DateTime TimeStamp { get; set; }
    public T Variable { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And then you can instantiate the type using reflection methods:

```
Type type = Type.GetType("System.Int32");
Type genericizedType = typeof(OPC_UA<>).MakeGenericType(type);
dynamic opc_ua = Activator.CreateInstance(genericType);
opc_ua.Variable = 5;  // For example
```